# Formly Repeated Section with length input

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-formly, ngx-formly, form-layout

```
   {
          key: 'skewNumber',
          type: '#custom-input',
          className: 'col-6',
          props: {
            type: 'number',
            label: 'No. of skew :',
            placeholder: 'No. of skew',
            required: true,
          },
          expressions: {
            hide: "!(model.isStructSkew ==='Yes')",
          },
          hooks: {
            onInit: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
              return field.formControl?.valueChanges.pipe(
                startWith(field.formControl?.value),
                filter((v) => v > 0),
                tap((value) => {
                  if (this.model.skewAngle.length !== value) {
                    this.model.skewAngle.length = value;
                    this.model = { ...this.model, skewNumber: value };
                  }
                })
              );
            },
          },
        },
        {
          key: 'skewAngle',
          type: 'repeat',
          fieldArray: {
            type: 'input',
            key: 'skewAngleDegree',
            props: {
              label: 'Skew Angle',
              required: true,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Repeat Compoent template :-

```
template: ` <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let f of field.fieldGroup; let i = index" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-6">
      <formly-field [field]="f" ></formly-field>
    </div>
  </div>`,
})
export class RepeatTypeComponent extends FieldArrayType {}
```

I am trying to generate multiple input fields based on the skewNumber value and fields are generating as expected, But I want a way to change the labels of those generated fields

currently every field that is being generated is having same label name which is Skew Angle but I want something like this :-
Skew Angle 1, Skew Angle 2 , Skew Angle 3 based on the number input skewNumber.

Can anyone help me with this? If possible try out the similar code in stackblitz and post the answer here. Thank You.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj7prg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts